# GraphQL | Can we implement search by programming language in GitHub GraphQL API using Directives?

Tags: github, graphql

I'm experimenting with GraphQL and I want to create a GraphQL script for advanced search. I'm stuck at figuring out how to search for a repository containing a specific language. For example, I only want to search for repos written in Kotlin. This is what my query looks like

```
query AdvancedSearch($query: String!, $type: SearchType!, $numOfResults: Int!, $nextPageCursor: String) {
search(type: $type, query: $query, first: $numOfResults, after: $nextPageCursor) {
    pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
    }
    repositoryCount
    nodes {
        ... on Repository {
            name
            nameWithOwner
            description
            languages(first: 100) {
                nodes {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm thinking along the lines of having a @skip directive in languages, something like

```
languages(first:100) @skip(if:$filterLanguage != "Kotlin")
```

I don't want to pass "language:kotlin" in the search query, I want to do this using Directives. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the spec: http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec--skip

> The `@skip` directive may be provided for fields, fragment spreads, and inline fragments, and allows for conditional exclusion during execution as described by the if argument.

In other words, the `@skip` (and its `@include` counterpart) directive only determines whether a field is included in the request. Skipping a field this way is the same as not including it in the first place. Additionally, the `if` argument of the directive may only be passed `true`, `false` or a Boolean variable -- no sort of expression syntax is supported.

More importantly, **including or omitting a particular field will have no impact on how any parent field is executed**. If your intent is to modify what results are returned by the `search` field, then you need to provide the appropriate arguments to that field. The schema *could* provide some kind of argument to let you filter by languages specifically but that does not appear to be the case -- the only way to do it is through the `query` argument.